# Redux Form converting payload from Number to String on blur

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to isolate why React/Redux/Redux-Form is automatically converting my `payload` to a string, whenever I focus and blur a input field.

There must be some process that is interfering but I don't know how to troubleshoot.

I've tried using the ReduxDevTools Chrome Extension which basically outputs :

```
type(pin): "@@redux-form/INITIALIZE"
▶meta(pin)
▶payload(pin)
   Amount(pin): 2222

type(pin): "@@redux-form/FOCUS"
▶meta(pin)

type(pin): "@@redux-form/BLUR"
▶meta(pin)
   touch(pin): true
   payload(pin): "2222.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use redux-form?
If your data *can* remain within the context of the component, it should.

Here is one option, provided you don't need your data in the global app state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import wrapStateHelpers from 'react-state-helpers';

class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    const { mut, values: { someNumber } } = this.props;
    return (
      <input
        type='number'
        value={someNumber}
        onChange={mut('someNumber', parseInt)} />
    );
  }
}

export default wrapStateHelpers(Example);
```

This just provides an event handler and wrapping component that manages form state in the component-level-state and then passes that state as the `values` object in the props to your component.

Note the `parseInt` passed to `mut`. Input fields nearly always return a string, and `react-state-helpers` provides an api for data conversion (second parameter to `mut` can be any function)

Here is a link to the project / docs, if this

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case was painfully obvious in retrospect. I was using `normalize` to format the value using `.toFixed(2)` which unknown to me, always returns a string.